# Pagination Issue thru axio request

Tags: laravel, pagination

I am trying to send axio fetch request to laravel backend

```
url = /search?searchBy=product_id&searchValue=sprint-10

Route::get('/search', 'ProductController@search');

 public function search(Request $request){
 $requestQuery = $request->query(); //to get all the queries

     $searchBy = $request->searchBy;
     $searchValue = $request->searchValue;

     if( $searchBy == 'product_id' && $searchValue == true ) {
         $product = Product::where("product_id", 'like', "%$searchValue%")->paginate(5);
         return response($product);
     } else {
         return $requestQuery;
     }

    }
```

this return the products with pagination option ...when I click on next_page_url , it goes to

next_page_url: "http://sprint/search?page=2",

i am not getting the results from page 2..

could you please advise, how i can solve this issue....

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer ...

we have to use appends($request->except('page'));

```
$product = Product::where("product_id", 'like', "%$searchValue%")->paginate(5);
return $product->appends($request->except('page'));
```

the result :

```
next_page_url: "http://sprint-laravel/search?searchBy=product_id&searchValue=sprint-10&page=2",
```